# Where does a hane turn?

Tags: handwriting, stroke-type

For characters with hane, does all hane do the sharp upward turn to be always on the left side? Please provide an example for characters with hane turning upwards to the right if there is any.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but there is an informative video on simple strokes at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvjN9qfdEjA around the 5:50 mark you will see 左はね.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I just wanted to find out if a hane only appears on the left. Later on I found out that a hane could appear on both sides depending on the character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hane to the right can also be seen in some characters, an example would be け.

A hane, therefor can be observed to have a sharp turn pointing upwards on either the left or the right side.

水 is an example a character where the hane is on the left side.